# Is it possible to use PowerShell to connect to QuickBooks

Tags: powershell, quickbooks

I am trying to use PowerShell to access QuckBooks using QBXML and I have not been able to create the connection to the com object.

Using QuickBooksAPITestKit  I was able to successfully test that the SDK is properly installed and working. So I am obviously not clear on how to connect to the Request Processor.

**examples in the SDK docs**

```
Dim MyQbXMLRP2 As QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2
Set MyQbXMLRP2 = New QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2
```

I am in the prleliminary stages of this project and am simply trying to create the com object in powershell to confirm that I can do it before I start writing the powershell scripts to call from my app. So far I have not had success with this...

**my code**

```
$myqbxmlrp2 = New-Object -com Interop.QBXMLRP2Lib
$myqbxmlrp2 = New-Object -com QBXMLRP2Lib
$myqbxmlrp2 = New-Object -com Interop.QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2
$myqbxmlrp2 = New-Object -com QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2
```

I can get a connection to the QuickBooks application...

```
$myQBComObject = New-Object -com QuickBooks.Application
```

I don't see that is going to be of much help as I need to talk to the Request Processor.

Can someone show me how to do this in PowerShell?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. I had to install QBXMLRP (installer is in the SDK) as administrator, but I think the main problem was I was using the the 64 bit version of PowerShell instead of the x86 version. So...

$myqbxmlrp = New-Object -com QBXMLRP.RequestProcessor

works! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'd like to note that I too tried using the QB documenation's example of `QBXMLRP2Lib.RequestProcessor2` and found that such a com object cannot be created!  At least not in a universal manner throughout the environment.  It think you have to link to the actual QBXMLRP2.dll?  An explicit registration via Regsrvr32 succeeds on that file, but appears to accomplish nothing.  The OLE COM object inspector fails to show it's existence too...

Comment: I'd also note that I could not create any of these objects with VBScript (and yes I ran as admin or otherwise in either a 64 or 32 bit context to no avail.)  Yet, I was able to create a `QBXLMRP.RequestProcessor` com object in Python...  This api is very funky and poorly documented it seems for such a popular application and a common need to programmatically tap it!